# Can I get a response back when a user rates my app or taps "not now" for app store review request poppups?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, skstorereviewcontroller

I've added an app review request poppup in a few places around my app via [this method: SKStoreReviewController.requestReview().](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) I want to ensure that they are placed in effective spots so users feel inclined to give my app a review rather than skipping the request poppup and tapping "Not Now". I was wondering if it is possible to get a callback or a response back once the user has selected one of the two options: **"☆☆☆☆☆" (some rating) OR "Not Now"**.. Would it be possible to create an extension for the `SKStoreReviewController` that sends back a response from these buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My consensus is that this is not possible in a straightforward way as Apple wants to keep it proprietary so developers don't penalize users for not rating apps when given a prompt. The code for the SKStoreReviewController (for the actual buttons "Not Now" and giving the star rating) is proprietary.